# Font size inside subequations environment!

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath

How I can change the font size inside the `subequations` environment? See below:

```
\begin{equation}
    \textstyle
    \xi_{1} = A + B + C;
\end{equation}
```

The command `\textstyle` works fine inside the equation environment, but inside the `subequations` environment (see below, again) does not works.

```
\begin{subequations}
    \textstyle
    \begin{eqnarray}
      \xi_{1} = A + B + C \\
      \xi_{2} = E + F + G \\
      \xi_{3} = H + I + J
    \end{eqnarray}
\end{subequations}
```

I give errors:

> "Missing $ inserted.", "Missing \endgroup inserted.", "You can't use \halign in math mode", etc.

If I put `\textstyle` inside `eqnarray` it works, but then I need put in all equations.

Please, how I can change the math font size inside the `subequations` environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You need to move the `\textstyle` to be _after_ `\begin{eqnarray}`.  But, why do you want to do that? Also, you should  [avoid `eqnarray` as per this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Comment: If I put `\textstyle` after `\begin{eqnarray}` it is applied only to first equation. :((

Comment: The `eqnarray` environment is badly deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore, in *any* LaTeX document. For more information see the posting [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define an `alignts` environment that's the same as `align`, but uses `\textstyle` throughout.

The problem with long alignments is solved by issuing `\allowdisplaybreaks`. I tested with 216 equations without any problem. Don't use `eqnarray` under any circumstances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\alignts@preamble\align@preamble
\patchcmd{\alignts@preamble}{\displaystyle}{\textstyle}{}{}
\patchcmd{\alignts@preamble}{\displaystyle}{\textstyle}{}{}

\def\alignts{\let\align@preamble\alignts@preamble\start@align\@ne\st@rredfalse\m@ne}
\let\endalignts\endalign
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\begin{alignts}
\xi_{1} &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\xi_{2} &= \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \\
\xi_{3} &= \bigvee_i v_i
\end{alignts}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Embed this in a `subequations` environment, the result will be the same as `subequations` only changes the `equation` counter and has no influence on the typesetting of the equations.

If you insist in using `eqnarray`, it's just the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\eqnarrayts\eqnarray
\patchcmd{\eqnarrayts}{\displaystyle}{\textstyle}{}{}
\patchcmd{\eqnarrayts}{\displaystyle}{\textstyle}{}{}
\let\endeqnarrayts\endeqnarray
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarrayts}
\xi_{1} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \\
\xi_{2} = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \\
\xi_{3} = \bigvee_i v_i
\end{eqnarrayts}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @egreg, thanks by your attention. This seems a good approach and it works to more equations as I need. But when I try use it in my big text using memoir class nothing happens. Why?! :(

Comment: @user901366 I see no difference if I change `article` into `memoir`, so I guess there's more that this. Try making a minimal example and to be more specific about “nothing happens”, but in a new question.

Comment: Ok, in your MWE works, then is a useful answer, thanks! I will investigate better the problem with memoir.